# I installed Yarn and now create-react-app initially installs 879 dependencies

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I learned about Yarn and wanted to try it with React so I installed Yarn, and now when I run `create-react-app hello`, one of the scripts appear to be `yarn add v0.24.6`, which installs 879 dependencies into my `node_modules` directory.

Why is this happening and how do I make it stop? Or do I just not understand Yarn and this is supposed to be something I want?

Answer (score 1):

Were you using npm2 before? With it, you'd only see your app's direct dependencies in `node_modules` and *their* dependencies (i.e. your app's transitive dependencies) would be tucked away in nested `node_modules` dirs.

Yarn and npm >= 3 flatten dependencies in `node_modules`, so you're seeing all of `react-scripts`' direct dependencies *and* all of its transitive dependencies.

Comment: Got it. Just didn't realize that create-react-app had that many dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Every package we use might depends on others packages.

`yarn` and `npm > 3` use flat structure for resolving dependencies of other packages dependencies. So, your `node_modules` folder container long list of folders.

`npm < 3` use `nested tree` structure. So, your `node_modules` folder container few list of folders and dependencies of other packages nested inside `package/node_modules` folders.

#### so, why use `npm > 3 or yarn`?

Those are fast for resolving dependencies. I hope you have not yet experience on waiting for 1hours or more after `npm install` :D.

#### why yarn over npm?

There are lots of articles written on this topic. Just google it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Makes more sense now.